# ¿Necesito saber como resolver esta respuesta de un servidor de go daddy en mi servidor local funciona con el codigo de abajo?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

### 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

esta es la conexion a la base de datos

```
<?php
  $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "contraseña", " nombre bd");
    //if (!$conexion){
   //echo 'Error al conectar a la base de datos';
   //}
  //else {
  //  echo 'conectado a la base de datos'; 
 //}
?>
```

---

y esta es el registro

```
<?php
   include 'conectar.php';
  //recibir los datos y almacenarlos en variables
  $correo= $_POST["correo"];
 //consulta para insertar
 $insertar = "INSERT INTO **tnombre de la tabla de 
 bd**(correo) VALUES ('$correo')";
//Ejecutar consulta
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);

 if (!$resultado) {
    echo 'Error al registrarse';
 } else{
    echo 'Usuario registrado Exitosamente';
 }
 //Cerrar conexion
  mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Un error 500 significa "Algo ha ido mal". En tiempos se solía dar más información con el mensaje, pero hoy en día en general se opina que dar más información supone un riesgo de que alguien ataque/use fallos de la aplicación usando esos datos. Con el código que adjuntas lo único que se puede revisar es que sea correcto, pero si dices que te funciona en local se supone que es correcto. Deberías buscar los logs que proporcione godaddy (ni idea de dónde pueden estar) y dar esa información para que se te pueda responder.

Comment: error 500 , es muy dificil, coloca tu archivo raiz php `error_reporting(E_ALL);display_errors(true);` luego que tengas el error mas claro por favor agregalo a la pregunta y con gusto te ayudaremos

Comment: Gracias estoy trabajando en esto, espero resolverlo